# Detect Windows hosts changes

Tags: windows

After some a requests of supports by users, i have found into `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` my website, eg.:

```
127.0.0.1 mywebsite.com
```

users say they don't have made it, perhaps a third party software (eg. anti virus) has blocked my website for some unknown reason..

**There is a way for detect who has changed the hosts file**? eg. Event Viewer, logs, etc.

Comment: hosts is a common file, and the entry you're looking at is a default entry in every hosts file that has not been removed. It is also preceded by a hash or pound sign "#", corrrect?

Comment: sorry, i have used example.com, but i mean my website...

Comment: Windows offers file auditing, but I believe it has to be enabled before the activity you wish to audit occurs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/apply-a-basic-audit-policy-on-a-file-or-folder

Comment: Got it. Thanks for clearing that up and editing the question. 1 you should look into file auditing, and 2 you should check for viruses and malicious activity on the computers you support. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/apply-a-basic-audit-policy-on-a-file-or-folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for detect who has changed the hosts file? eg. Event Viewer, logs, etc.

tl;dr: Absolutely yes.

If you have money you can use [Glasswire](https://www.glasswire.com) without any headache.
Glasswire has an option in security settings to monitor 'hosts' and 'lmhosts' file changes.

[image: GlassWire_Monitor_hosts_file]

If you want free solution use [TraceView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/traceview) in Windows Driver Kit.
Install Windows Driver Kit
→ run TraceView as administrator
→ Create New Log Session → Kernel Logger → File I/O → Log Trace Event Data to File
→ Enter ETL file path as you want.

[image: TraceView-Kernel-Mode-Trace]

Use [TraceFmt](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/tracefmt) to display and find your required file change.
Required command: `tracefmt.exe C:\path\to\ETL-File-Name.etl -displayonly| find /i "hosts"`

If you want more free software I have a open-source project [TraceEvent](https://github.com/Biswa96/TraceEvent) @GitHub which is in development.